# How would I encode this is JSON format (multiple lists)

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have 6 different data lists a[], b[], c[], d[], e[], f[]. How would I go about encoding this into a JSON format so it reads like this:

```
{
   "date":a[0]
     {
       "value1":b[0]
       "value2":c[0]
       "value3":d[0]
       "value4":e[0]
       "value5":f[0]
     }
   "date":a[1]
     {
       "value1":b[1]
       "value2":c[1]
       "value3":d[1]
       "value4":e[1]
       "value5":f[1]
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON.

Comment: You can either have a string or a dictionary as a value for a key. Can't have both.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same key `"date"`

Comment: Maybe you mean `a[0]: { ... }, a[1]: { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've posted isn't valid JSON. I suspect you actually want:

```
{
   a[0]:
     {
       "value1":b[0]
       "value2":c[0]
       "value3":d[0]
       "value4":e[0]
       "value5":f[0]
     },
   a[1]:
     {
       "value1":b[1]
       "value2":c[1]
       "value3":d[1]
       "value4":e[1]
       "value5":f[1]
     }
}
```

You can do this by looping over all the lists.

```
import json
result = {}
for date, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 in zip(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    result[date] = { "value1": value1, "value2": value2, "value3": value3, "value4": value4, "value5": value5 }
json_string = json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Yep that was essentially what I was looking for. I'm unfamiliar with json, so I wasn't sure of it's valid syntax. Thanks alot for the tip though!

Comment: JSON is just a way of representing data as text. Think in terms of the underlying data, not JSON syntax. What dictionary were you trying to construct?

Comment: I got it all sorted. Next, however, I need to learn the correct implementation of this structure into a Keras LSTM :D Thanks for the help man!